# How can I make this marguerite nice again?

Tags: plant-care

I bought these marguerites last summer (2 plants) and they survived the winter in a pot.  It now looks woody and straggly with lots of brown leaves.  Is there any way I can revive it to make it look neat and healthy again? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut it back to about 6 inches, fertilize it and keep it watered - but only if its warm enough. I don't know where you are, but in the UK, its a bit risky to cut it back hard right now because the weather is about to turn frosty again for a couple of days. If you live somewhere the weather has warmed and  you're not at risk of sudden hard frosts, do it now, otherwise, wait till end of April/early May,  depending on the weather.